# Third-Party G.729 Implementation for iOS (32 and 64-bits)

Tags: ios, pjsip, armv7, arm64, g729

I'm trying to find a good G.729A implementation (free or paid) to include in PJSip.
I've found one that is being used in CSipSimple but I can't compile it for ARM64, only for ARMv7.

I've already requested quotes to Vocal and Adaptive Digital.

Anyone has some references?

Best regards